# How to update a program based on a downloaded file

Tags: updates, visual-studio-code

I want to update ***VS code*** without updating all applications. And I want to do it through terminal By the downloaded file of newest version.

can I somehow introduce the file.deb in my memory as the source of the update?

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.
Thank you All!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways.

- Install the gdebi installer for .deb files.

  ```
  sudo apt install gdebi
  ```

  Then open the .deb file with gdebi to install it.
- Open a terminal in the directory containing the .deb package, and install it directly with apt.

  ```
  sudo apt install ./filename.deb
  ```

Later on, to update the software database,

```
sudo apt update
```

Then, you can update the whole system with `sudo apt dist-upgrade`, or selectively upgrade vscode with `sudo apt install code`

Comment: OK its so good but a question : I have this app right now so if i `install` it -> its automatically  be update ?

Comment: According to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux, the .deb package will automatically add its repository to the system, and afterwards, you can update it through the package manager like any other software.